# C#:Splitting Lists according to a property

Tags: c#

I have a list which contains properties of the book such as Chapter Name and Part Name. These are dynamic and can vary.

```
 List<TOCModel> li = new List<TOCModel>();
```

TOCModel Class contains

```
public class TOCModel
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Part { get; set; }
    }
```

From this list, I need to create seperate

elements in the front end like

```
Part 1
 Chapter 1
 Chapter 2
 Chapter 3
Part 2
    ... 
    ...
    ... and so on.
```

Since the list is dynamic and I can even get more than 10 parts, it is not possible to use if or for loops. Can anyone say how this can be achieved?

Comment: how the list is given. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I get the values from the database through data reader. I tried using group by in linq but since the count is dynamic I cant achieve it

Comment: You haven't given enough information to answer the question.  What have you tried so far?  And why does a dynamic list or the number of items in its item array have to do with anything?  A `for` or `foreach` loop is exactly how you'd resolve this if you don't use Linq, and I don't see anything here that would tell me Linq wont work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done very easily with LINQ. See the following snippet on how to output the grouped chapters on the console, but - of course - you won't be restricted to that

```
var groupedTocs = li.GroupBy(toc => toc.Part);
foreach(var part in groupedTocs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(part.Key);
    foreach(var chapter in part)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{chapter.Header}");
    }
}
```

Comment: In this solution, I am able to get Part Name seperately. But the issue is, Based on parts I have to create <li> elements. Suppose I have 10 distinct Parts in the list, it is not possible 10 lists right?

Comment: That's exactly what is it. You have ten groups, one for each part and can iterate over all groups and over the items of one group.